# How to use VertX web template with dynamic url?

Tags: java, vert.x

Given code below that handle GET request to `/article/:id`. If i make request to `/article/1` VertX would look for template file in `article/1.hbs` instead of `article.hbs`.

```java
TemplateEngine engine = HandlebarsTemplateEngine.create();
TemplateHandler handler = TemplateHandler.create(engine);

router.get("/article/:id").handler(handler);
```

How do i reuse `article.hbs` with dynamic url without manually calling `engine.render()`?

This is my current solution by manually calling `engine.render()`

```java
    Handler<RoutingContext> render(String template) {

        return (ctx) -> {
            engine.render(ctx.data(), "templates/" + template, res -> {
                if (res.succeeded()) {
                    ctx.response().end(res.result());
                } else {
                    ctx.fail(res.cause());
                }
            });
        };
    }
```

is there any solution more elegant? like express' `res.render()`?

Comment: There's no other solution, the template handler is built to look for a template named after the relative http path